# Karaf cellar cluster

Tags: hazelcast, apache-karaf

I have 3 nodes in KARAF cluster.
Node 1, Node 2 and Node 3.
If i turn off Node 1 and do cluster:feature-uninstall on Node 2 then Node 3 is synced with Node 2 and the feature is successfully uninstalled. When i turn on Node 1 then Node 2 and Node 3 gets the state from Node 1 and the feature is installed on them.

I tried this with feature-repo remove but still the same.. When turned off node gets started all the nodes get the state from that node.

Config:
org.apache.karaf.cellar.groups.cfg:

```
default.bundle.sync = cluster
default.config.sync = cluster
default.feature.sync = cluster
default.obr.urls.sync = cluster
default.balanced.servlet.sync = cluster
```